# AWS Redshift does not set integer defaults when copying from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Create query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.test_table ( "test_field1" INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, "test_field2" INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)
```

test_file.csv (note that second row hasn't first column value):

```
test_field1,test_field2
100, 234
,30542
```

test.manifest:

```
{"entries":[{"url":"s3://MY_BUCKET_NAME/some_path/test_file.csv","mandatory":true}]}
```

COPY Query:

```
COPY test.test_table
("test_field1", "test_field2")
FROM 's3://MY_BUCKET_NAME/some_path/test.manifest'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=some_access_key;aws_secret_access_key=some_secret'
CSV
IGNOREHEADER 1
MANIFEST
REGION AS 'some-region-n'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
ACCEPTINVCHARS
```

When I execute copy query, I got error from stl_load_error:

> Missing data for not-null field

Why? I tried to omit `test_field1` from the query but got another error:

> Extra column(s) found.

When I change field type to VARCHAR (256), redshift returns `OK`.
Maybe I miss something, it's too strange for me to understand.

Comment: looks like a bug - i suggest you contact aws support for this one (and report back here if you find a good answer?)

Comment: I added the same question to [aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=273461). Hope they will respond quickly..