# Redshift copy does not add integer defaults when copying csv from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Create table statement:

```sql
create table test_users (id int primary key, company_id INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
```

When I am trying to copy a csv file from S3 to Redshift with null values in `company_id` column, it throws the error: `Missing data for not-null field`

However, manually inserting data works fine:

```sql
Insert into test_users VALUES (1)
```

A similar question is here: [AWS Redshift does not set integer defaults when copying from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741381/aws-redshift-does-not-set-integer-defaults-when-copying-from-s3)

Comment: [CREATE TABLE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html) says: _"If a COPY operation with a defined column list omits a column that has a DEFAULT value, the COPY command inserts the value of default_expr."_ Can you show us the `COPY` command you are using to load the data? Does it contain a list of column names?

Comment: What @JohnRotenstein said is correct. Are you using the right delimiter? Can you please provide more details from stl_load_errors table?